# Onedrive SDK Authentication Redirect Issue with Query Param

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, redirect, onedrive

Currently, I'm trying to integrate the OneDrive SDK onto a website.  However, I'm having issue with redirecting with authentication.

Normal route:

1. User goes to the website.  It clicks on a button to single sign onto there OneDrive
2. User gets redirected to OneDrive Authorization page.
3. Once authentication, user gets redirected to where they left off.  This redirect is specified in the OneDrive's SDK account.  However, it seems that they don't allow query params in the redirect URL.

Is there a way around this?

The only thing I could figure out is using a URL that is an alias for the URL with the query params, but that just seems like a hack solution. It's hard to believe that there isn't a way for a user to redirect with query params to indicate at what stage they left off on the site.

Example of invalid redirect url as http://skydpk.com/index.php?a=ap&addon=file_sharing&page=skydrive

Any advice appreciated,

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

You can try registering your base URL as the redirect URL and just before initiating authorization action append the parameters to the redirect URL.

Redirect URL at one drive app dashboard : http://skydpk.com/index.php

Authorization URL

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=<your client id>&scope=<scope>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://skydpk.com/index.php?a=ap&addon=file_sharing&page=skydrive
```

Comment: This won't work....I get an error about the query params are not allowed.  Have you gotten this to work?

Comment: Yes. I have whatever comes before "?" as the redirect URL in the One Drive app dashboard. While preparing authorization URL for the user, I will be adding redirect URL plus the parameters I want and then will be posting it to the browser. This redirect_uri value which I just prepared will be the last parameter of the authorization request.